# "Panic" bug when trying to run "Hello world" program using android SDK

Tags: java, android, sdk

I have this problem when trying to run hello world program using android SDK.

PANIC: Could not open AVD config file: C:\Users\׳�׳™׳›׳�׳�׳•׳�׳™׳›׳�.android\avd\em111.avd/config.ini

I understand that the problem is the bad path the system is looking.

So i try to redirect the link to the right link.

I can use mklink: mklink mklink /J "wrong path" "correct path".

But how can i speccify this weird link: 
 C:\Users\׳�׳™׳›׳�׳�׳•׳�׳™׳›׳�?

Any ideas?

Comment: are you using eclipse or just the SDK itself?

Comment: plase see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6641498/android-emulator-cant-start-cause-of-wrong-folder

Comment: have you used it successfully in the past? maybe need to reinstall?

Comment: Its a bad path which will not be fixed via MS style sym links.

What does your systems environment display for ANDROID_HOME and your user.home?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the thread pointed to in the comments illustrates, the graphical AVD editor chooses its own path where it puts stuff:

http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/devices/managing-avds-cmdline.html#DefaultLocation

You'll want to either move your AVDs to the 'original' directory, or if as it looks, the path has been corrupted, look at your ANDROID_HOME environment variable and see if that is correct.

After this, you may want to simply use the graphic AVD editor to re-recreate the em111 emulator you were working on, i.e. just make a new one...

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance, but how can i check if my ANDROID_HOME environment variable is correct?

Comment: This illustrates how to check all env variables: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310519 ...