# Eclipse PANIC: Could not open

Tags: android, eclipse

I just installed Eclipse with Android plugin and created Virtual Android Device. When I try and run the program I get the following error: *Starting emulator for AVD 'AVD3'
PANIC: Could not open: AVD3*

Please, help

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6641498/android-emulator-cant-start-cause-of-wrong-folder

Comment: I saw it. But this is not solving my problem

Comment: The best way is to remove all Android files from computer. Restart and install again.
Or reinstall system

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem as you ... and I reinstalled Android SDK Manager mode only user ... and suddenly I moved my config in my new virtual trees.