# Why am I getting "PANIC: Could not open" when trying to start an emulator?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator, adt, eclipse-adt

I have seen a few similar questions on this topic, such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9009872/android-eclipse-panic-could-not-open) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6641498/android-emulator-cant-start-cause-of-wrong-folder), but whereas those two questions deal with an incorrect path, I am not getting a path at all.

[image]

Am I missing something? All I have done is create a virtual Android device as per [this tutorial](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/running-app.html), and have then run into this error.

Looking at the details of the virtual device, its path is `D:\.android\avd\VirtualDeviceNexus.avd`, which **does** exist on my system.

[image]

Any ideas? (Or is this just the same error with a different look, one year of Android advancements later?)

Comment: Please open commander, then `CD` to your folder `[Android-SDK]\tools`, and run this command line: `emulator.bat @VirtualDeviceNexus -debug-all`, then post the log which will be printed out here. I'm not sure `emulator.bat` or `emulator.exe` since I don't have Windows, but I think there will be one of them.

Comment: @LaiVung Same message. http://i.stack.imgur.com/Cplw5.png (And yes, I had previously changed the name)

Comment: Thanks. But I'm sorry I can't help with that info. I found some related questions on SO like [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9009872/android-eclipse-panic-could-not-open), [this one with an accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15103782/avd-panic-could-not-open-not-a-path-issue) and [issue #19084](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=19084) on Android project. I hope they would be useful.